# Add third party libs to pyd file compiled with cython and packaging on exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, compilation, cython, pyinstaller

I am using cython to compile one file from py to pyd, I create my setup.py as follows:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = "My App",
    ext_modules = cythonize(['src\\lib\\module.py'])
```

it is import in main.py as follows:

`from src.lib.module import myclass`

When I run my app with command "python main.py" it is work but when run el .exe generated with pyinstaller it throw exception ImportError No moduled named module.

I try import the module.pyd on hidden-import on spec file of pyinstaller, and then I get an error, No module import requests, request is used on module.pyd.

if I have installed requests so why cython or pyinstaller no import the module or what is the real problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a couple of things without seeing too much code...

Do you really want the name of the extension to be "src.libs.myGridLayout" ? Meaning, do you want to do

```
import src.libs.myGridLayout
```

in your python file? If this is your design, then that is what you do. The name is the name of the actual extension.

The library_dir is where to look for "external" libraries. (like Windows.lib) Cython will link the proper libraries for your project for the code you wrote, but for anything else, that is what you put in the "libraries" directory.

BTW, what is "namelibrary.lib" ? If it is a library you want to use in yoru project, then you simply add the path to where that library is found, and add "namelibrary" to the libraries.

Just by looking at the way you wrote this extension for cython, I would highly recommend that you go a little slower, and read / learn a little bit more on how to set up a project, and how to use these Extensions. Good luck! :)

Comment: For now, I solved my problem with pyinstaller hooks, Try again later with extension. As external extensions I have a requests but the most of my import they are internal libraries created by me, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your pyInit file to create the lib, you can set the libraries and the library directories for the project to link to. For example

`extensions = [
    Extension(name="xxxx",sources=["xxx.pyx"],
    libraries=["myclass"],
    library_dirs=["/src/libdirectory"],
    language="c++",),`
]

This tells the cython linker to look for the library. One thing to note, for gnu compilers make sure you name your library "libmyclass.so" if you want the linker to see "myclass"

Comment: Jeje, Im a little lost, 1.- I work on windows, I named my libs as for example "my_module.py" and their class Module, ¿Could this give me trouble in windows?

2.- My directory structure is more o less: 
mainfolder->main.py, setup.py
mainfolder->libs->__init__.py, my_module.py
with pyInit your reference to main.py or __init__.py on libs folder  or setup.py

Comment: Something more, grieves me to say but I do not understand the code that you passed me, I check a little documentation and back.

Comment: This simply means the .exe linker can not find your module. If you create the extension above like I showd you (see the cython docs on extension) then you can tell the exe where to find your libs.  You have 2 other choices  your module to a place where the .exe ccan see it

Comment: OR add a directory to your Windows PATH

Comment: I try with the extension and get error, LNK1181: can not open input file 'namelibrary.lib, the code that i use is : `Extension('src.libs.MyGridLayout', sources=["src\\libs\\MyGridLayout.py"], library_dirs=["src\\libs\\checkbox"], libraries=["checkbox"])`. My library MyGridLayout make `from src.libs.checkbox import MyCheckBox` Both module MyGridLayout and checkbox is located in mainfolder->src->libs-> modulehere, and setup.py on mainfolder.

Comment: Okay, a couple of things (without seeing too much code)